# How to save file starting with . (dot) in Sublime without prompt

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

When I try to save new file with filename starting with `.` (dot), Sublime prompts me, if I really want to do that.

Is there a way to make Sublime save the file without asking me? Either with configuration, 3rd party plugin or with my own. At this point I take anything.

I'm using Sublime 3.2.2 build 3211 on MacOS Big Sur

[image: annoying sublime message screenshot]

Comment: This has to do with the operating system, not Sublime. Try searching [apple.se] or [su] for allowing dotfiles.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99213/is-it-possible-to-always-show-hidden-dotfiles-in-open-save-dialogs may work, I don't remember if it also allows saving dotfiles.

Comment: Saving using the Sublime Text console may work, it's worth a try. Open the console and use the `retarget()` method to set the file path of the active file/buffer/view, and then use `run_command()` to save. e.g. `view.retarget("/Users/MyUserName/.testsave")` and `view.run_command("save")`. If it works it'll be easy enough to use those commands in a simple plugin.